# How can I test my specific port is open or blocked?

Tags: ubuntu, port, service

I want to run a service which require to connect with some source using *port 20000* but it is not connecting. I want to test my this port is blocked or open.

Comment: This question is perhaps a bit short on words, but try using `netstat -an` or `netstat -lnptu` to figure out whether port 20000 is in LISTENING or perhaps ESTABLISHED state. I assume you are talking about a TCP connection here - if UDP your problem is something else. Add more details - then maybe better answers (and even a positive score) will come :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try [NMAP](http://nmap.org) to scan ports that are "open" on you local machine like:

> nmap -sS -O -p20000 127.0.0.1

Or to a netstat to check what port is used by a service.

Like so:

> netstat -lnptu

Comment: netstat -a | find "LISTENING" ?? not a joke?

Comment: @ADM, Sorry i forgot the Ubuntu part... Changed the "answer" :)

Comment: then | grep 20000? will it show that port is open?

Comment: @ADM, for exmaple you can use netstat -plnt | grep ':20000'  to look for the port is it`s LISTING to any service.

Answer (score 0):

### Useful utilities :

- 1.Telnet
- 2.nc
- 3.nmap

> Scenario: For checking remote system tcp 80 port status

### Usage :

```
telnet myserver.com 80 
nc -v myserver.com 80
nmap myserver.com 80
```

### Response Analysis :

if you get a time out or deny  : the port is not open

suppose if you get "Connection refused" : then port is open but process is not listerning

If you get a connection successful : Port is open and process is listen

### Solution:

start/restart the listening process (if connection refused)

Ask network team to monitor the connection we can confirm whether it is blocked from intermediate network firewall or from server firewall/iptables

Note :

- Suppose firewall configured to Reject packets instead of Drop then u
  will get "connection refused" error , so here in this case we can't
  ensure wheteher process is listern or not.

For checking udp port (like ntp) you can use below nc option

> nc -uzv yourserver.com 123